# Orux Maps raster display

Tags: raster

Does anyone know what format of raster images works with Orux Maps? I tried to export maps acc to Orux Maps specs from ArcGIS 10.1 in every possible format (Geotiff, GRID, jpeg2000...), loaded with a .tfw file and it always displayed a colorless tile.

Answer (score 1):

Note: your files need to be be geo-referenced (tfw filesfor tiff, .pgw for png)

> "OruxMapsDesktop. For your existing maps already callibrated for Ozi,
>   .kap, .tiff, .tfw, or simply an image file, use OruxMapsDesktop."

http://www.oruxmaps.com/oruxmapsmanual_en.pdf

also a useful link is

http://www.oruxmaps.com/Conversion_BSB_Raster_Charts.pdf
(not png can be used to)